# Laravel 5.2 - how can I create fixture or mock data for testing in passage way application

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5, mockery

I'm working on developing REST API web application to provide API to front-end technologies but my application is a bit complicated. It has to call to another web API first to request resource and then provide to front-end web application, that's why I call it a passage way application.

I'm going to have a unit test and an integration test. The unit test will focus on testing local fixtures, while integration test will instead focus on testing the fixtures from web API that my application need to call.

Currently, we've already done with integration but we haven't had a solution for the unit test yet. Does anybody has any suggestion on that?